# isalpha equivalent for wchar_t

Tags: c++, unicode, localization, wchar-t

what is the equivalent function for isalpha or isalnum using wchar_t?

wctype ?

an example would be nice also

thanks

Answer (score 14):

[`iswalpha`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/wide/iswalpha), [`iswalnum`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/wide/iswalnum). Same usage.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [`std::isaplha<charT>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/locale/isalpha/) from [`<locale>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/locale/). Could use that as `std::isalpha<wchar_t>`.

Answer (score 3):

You include tag "localization" in your question. In case of writing of international application you should clear define what do you mean under *alphabetical or numerical characters*. If you write programs for Windows I'll recommend you to use `GetStringTypeEx` function (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd318118.aspx). For example the code

```
BOOL bSuccess;
int isTrue;
WORD wCharType;

bSuccess = GetStringTypeExW (LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, CT_CTYPE1, L"a", 1, &wCharType);
if (wCharType & C1_ALPHA == C1_ALPHA) {
    // 
}
```

You can also use `CT_CTYPE3` or `CT_CTYPE2` to determne whether a charachter is an Ideographic or whether it is an European number.

To be more exact just try to use function `iswalpha`, `IsCharAlphaW`, `iswalnum`, `iswdigit` and `GetStringTypeExW` to test following charachters: L'a', L'ü', L'á', L'я' (Russian charackter), L'ノ' (Japanese charackter in Katakana), L'一' (1 in Japanese). You will see that

- iswalpha (L'ノ') return alpha
- IsCharAlphaW (L'ノ') return NOT alpha
- iswalnum (L'一') return alpha or digit
- iswdigit (L'一') return NOT digit

The code

```
bSuccess = GetStringTypeExW (LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, CT_CTYPE2, L"一", 1, &wCharType);
if ((wCharType & C2_EUROPENUMBER) == wCharType) {
    // numeric
}
```

say you that L"一" is NOT a european number. You can use `GetStringTypeExW` to destinduish european number from for example arabic number etc.

So I recommend you to specify your requirement more exactly and then choose the API based on the requirements. In general the usage of the C API is not the best way for an international application.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you define “equivalent.” The C character classes are quite simple minded compared to Unicode character classes. For example, if you want to test whether a given code point usually represents a letter (for some definition of “letter”), you could test for the general category `L`; if you want to check whether a given string comprises a valid identifier, you could use [UAX #31](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr31/), etc. `iswalnum` and `iswalpha` might give the intended result depending on the current “locale” setting.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, this is not possible under visual studio/windows, because wchar_t is 2 bytes on this platform and is unable to hold a unicode codepoint.

What you really need is a function accepting char*. You have one in [ICU](http://userguide.icu-project.org/) AFAIK.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049947/should-utf-16-be-considered-harmful

Comment: I'm pretty sure that half the point of Unicode is the whole multi-byte thing, where you don't need to be able to hold one codepoint in one character type, because it has the whole carry-over thing.

Comment: DeadMG, what thing are you talking about? I lost you somewhere...If you cannot pass a character to a function, you cannot know if it's a letter. So far so good - and you really cannot, this is life.

Answer (score 0):

The header is [`<wctype.h>`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/iswalnum.html).  The basic macro/function names have a 'w' in them:

```
int iswalpha(wint_t wc);
int iswalnum(wint_t wc);
```

Etc.

There are also the functions:

```
wctype_t wctype(const char *property);
int iswctype(wint_t wc, wctype_t desc);
```

You could write, for example:

```
if (iswctype(wc, wctype("alnum")))
    ...process a wide alphanumeric...
```

Or you could simply write:

```
if (iswalnum(wc))
    ...process a wide alphanumeric...
```