# C++ function that tells if a unicode point is a 'letter' and not number of punctuation

Tags: c++, unicode

Is there a `C++` function available that decides if a given Unicode point is a letter? I mean what's often described as `\p{L}` in regular expressions. So it could be a Latin, Greek, Cyrillic or other letter, as opposed to punctuation, numbers, etc., which, in unicode are also be represented by several other large code point ranges.

So what I'm asking for a function similar to this:

```
bool isUnicodeLetter(int32 codepoint);
```

Maybe in the boost or ICU libraries?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3378343/isalpha-equivalent-for-wchar-t) appears to be similar.

Comment: Functions that deal with Unicode should never ever take a single codepoint as though all characters can be represented as a single codepoint (because not all can be). You need a function like `bool isUnicodeLetter(std::u32string character);`. If you find a function that takes a codepoint then be sure to never use it because it's necessarily wrong.

Comment: @barnes53: This seems to contradict Daniel Trebbien's answer. The ICU library is a highly regarded standard unicode library. Are you saying they got it wrong?

Comment: @Frank I believe that function could be legitimately used as a query on whether the codepoint has a certain Unicode property, however it could easily be misused by someone wanting to classify _characters_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In ICU4C, the function is called [`u_isalpha()`](http://www.icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/uchar_8h.html#a86cc4f937e33bcea3772c6faf3e293c1):

> ```
> UBool u_isalpha(UChar32 c)
> ```
>
> Determines whether the specified code point is a letter character.
>
> True for general categories "L" (letters).

But be careful when using this as it is easy to misuse. `u_isalpha()` and the other functions in `uchar.h` are only designed to provide low-level access to Unicode character data.

Comment: Note that the name of the function is deceptive, in that it does test whether the code point has the `Alphabetic=Yes` Unicode character property; it only tests whether it has the `General_Category=Letter` property, which itself is any of `General_Category=Lowercase_Letter`,
`General_Category=Modifier_Letter`,
`General_Category=Other_Letter`,
`General_Category=Titlecase_Letter`,
`General_Category=Uppercase_Letter`, and nothing else.

Comment: @tchrist: I'm quite happy with that function. Why is the name deceptive? It tests for any letter property. What else would you want?

Comment: Well, I would want it to test the Unicode `alpha` property, which is something else. This would only work on the Latin script, because others have non-`Letter` codepoints with the `Other_Alphabetic` property.  In some scripts, it is useless to just test for simple letters.   Alphabetic is not just letters in Unicode.  Sorry.

Comment: Oh, do you have a typo in your first comment, then? "in that it does test whether the code point has the Alphabetic=Yes Unicode character property" Did you want to say "doesn't test"?

Comment: How is `u_isalpha` from ICU different from `std::iswalpha`, which I found on the related question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3378343/isalpha-equivalent-for-wchar-t?lq=1

Comment: @Frank: Just as the C and POSIX standards do not define the semantics of `isalpha()` beyond the ASCII range, the semantics of `std::iswalpha` is similarly only defined for the current wide character set, as specified by the `LC_CTYPE` category of the current locale.

Comment: BTW, in addition to `u_isalpha` I also found `u_isUAlphabetic(UChar32)`, which just checks the binary property `Alphabetic`.